# Use default music player in Dash

Tags: 12.10, unity-dash, music

When I select music file with Files & Folders lense, it loads it with default music player. But when I use Music lense, it loads file with Rhythmbox. How can I change this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately at this time the music lens only supports Rhythmbox and Banshee. When 13.04 is released the music lens will support

Audacious

Clementine

Guayadeque

Banshee

gMusicBrowser

Musique

and

Rhythmbox

For more information please refer to http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/02/100-scopes-list-ubuntu-13-04